# What are the risks with a self hosted registry and own certs in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

The setup:

I have a self hosted registry and use my own cert. I cannot login except when i set the registry to insecure.

Now everything works, but ofc it is saying that this is not secure.

what are the risks of a setup like this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to instruct every docker daemon to trust your certificate, but the security message is going to show up nevertheless.

Basically, it's just a debate about using Self-Signed Certificates vs. CA signed ones. Security wise, they both work the same way. So for testing purposes, it is completely sufficient.

Cons of using self-signed certs:

> - These certificates are not trusted by other applications/operating systems. This may lead to authentications errors etc.
> - Self-signed certificates life time is usually 1 year(s). These certificates need to be renewed/replaced every year, a big hassle to
>     maintain.
> - Self-signed certificates may use low hash and cipher technologies. Due this, the security level that implemented by self-signed
>     certificates may not satisfy the current Security Policy etc.
> - No support for advanced PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) functions (e.g. Online checking of the revocation list etc.).
> - Most of the advanced feathers of the server side applications required to impended a PKI (Public Key Infrastructure). By this,
>     self-signed certificates advantages cant be used
>
> Cons taken from:
>   https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/what-are-self-signed-certificates-and-disadvantages/

Answer (score 1):

An insecure registry can be replaced by a man in the middle, hijacked with DNS corruption, spied on to gather passwords, and any number of other attacks protected by a property configured TLS/SSL connection. A malicious registry server can result in code running as root on your host. So overall this is recommended against. The only default insecure registry is localhost since if that is hijacked, the host is already compromised.

Instead of switching to an insecure registry, please try to get your self signed CA to be trusted by either docker itself, or in the worst case, the entire host. Most of the docs describe doing this with `/etc/docker/certs.d/host:port/ca.crt`. There is an old issue describing this for Windows since the path is different and a colon isn't allowed in the directory name. The conclusion appears to be `C:\ProgramData\docker\certs.d\myregistrydomain.com5000\ca.crt` or possibly `C:\Users\<user>\.docker\certs.d\myregistrydomain.com5000\ca.crt` which may also vary with different install methods on Windows. You can review this issue and the linked docs here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21189
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#certificates
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/